# simple if else statement in syntax error in R

Tags: r

I would like to R to the following:
if LocID is equal to 3,4,7,8, 14 then data$newConc is equal to data$conc/2
else data$newConc <- data$conc   # else keep conc the same

```
data$newConc <- if(data$LocID == c(3,4,7,8,14))
data$conc/2 else data$conc

str(data)
 $ LocID     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ time      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ conc      : num  0.03695 0.0155 0.00738 0.00753 0.01795 ...
```

Warning:
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: The R code you've given isn't  valid...no balanced brackets? Did you mean `ifelse`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your code (which won't even run, due to a missing closing bracket?) you're trying to do (pseudocode):

```
foreach row in data
    if row$LocID is one of 3, 4, 7, 8, or 14
    THEN set row$newConc to row$conc/2
    ELSE set row$newConc to row$conc
```

To do this you use `ifelse`.

Also, if you want to test if a value is equal ot 3, 4, 7, 8 or 14, then don't use `==` -- that will return a *vector* of booleans, and `if` requires a *single* boolean, hence your error.

Either use `data$locID %in% c(3,4,7,8,14)` to return a *single* TRUE/FALSE, or use `any(data$locID == c(3,4,7,8,14))` to turn the vector of booleans into a single boolean:

You're comparing a scalar to a vector, and so your output is a vector. An `if` statement only takes in a single boolean (not a vector of booleans).

Either use `data$locID %in% c(3,4,7,8,14)` to return a *single* TRUE/FALSE, or use `any(data$locID == c(3,4,7,8,14))` to turn the vector of booleans into a single boolean:

```
data$newConc <- ifelse( data$locID %in% c(3,4,7,8,14),
                        data$conc/2,
                        data$conc )
```

Alternatively I could have used `ifelse( any(data$locID == c(3,4,7,8,14)), ... )`.